# unable to parse multiline regex pattern

Tags: regex

we are trying to parse multiline format on tomcat logs, if the pattern is not matching they are coming in a separate lines

This is the regex pattern I was running “`^(?<time>[0-9][^ ]* [^ ]* [^ ]*) (?<severity>[^ ]*) (?<msg>.*)`”

How can I parse multiline which can get the whole msg in a single line?

```
2021-06-28 10:51:01,175 EDT ERROR [MFTAgentBootstrap] {main} For input string: "" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
2021-06-28 10:48:49,781 EDT ERROR [MFTAgentBootstrap] {main} For input string: "" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
2021-06-28 10:48:49,781 EDT ERROR [MFTAgentBootstrap] {main} For input string: "" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
         at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
         at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
         at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
             at com.linoma.dpa.DPASettings.loadSettings(DPASettings.java:2050)
2021-06-28 10:51:01,175 EDT ERROR [MFTAgentBootstrap] {main} For input string: "" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
2021-06-28 10:51:01,175 EDT ERROR [MFTAgentBootstrap] {main} For input string: "" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

Comment: If you can't find a solution you can eat the line breaks with something like this `\r?\n +(?=(?<msg>.*))`, and then research.

Comment: I had the same problem i just created a copy file without line breaks and used reg exp against it

Comment: @PrasadKundeti - _Because regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool._

Comment: @Arkon88 check my answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

This regular expression continues to capture the group `(?<msg>)` as long as it finds lines starting with spaces along the way.

```
^(?<time>[0-9][^ ]* [^ ]* [^ ]*) (?<severity>[^ ]*) (?<msg>.*(?:\r?\n +.*)*)
```

[<kbd>**REGEX101 DEMO**</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/D3j7ma/1)

Comment: i tried with above pattern but it didnt worked out https://regex101.com/r/1mWWBq/1

Comment: It is not working because now you are using tabs instead of spaces. But no problem, with this fix you can match spaces and tabs:  `^(?<time>[0-9][^ ]* [^ ]* [^ ]*) (?<severity>[^ ]*) (?<msg>.*(?:\r?\n[ \t]+.*)*)`